# Template not loading with get_template_part or locate_template

Tags: shortcode, get-template-part

I have this simple template in a my_template.php file:

```
<div class="popup_canvas_container">
    <p>This is a template I'm gonna load</p>
</div>
```

And I implemented this function to load the template from custom shortcode:

```
public static function load_template($atts) {       
    function load_my_template() {
        ob_start();

        //if ( file_exists(TEMPLATE_MODULE_DIR . 'my-template.php') ) {
        //  include_once( TEMPLATE_MODULE_DIR . 'my-template.php' );
        //}


        get_template_part('my-template');
        //locate_template( TEMPLATE_MODULE_DIR . 'my-template.php', true, true );
        
        return ob_get_clean();
        
        //global $wpdb;                     
        //$current_user_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_email FROM newk3_users WHERE user_login = 'xxxxxx' " );       
        //$result = "<div class='box_external'><p>$current_user_id</p></div>";
        //$result = "This is return";       
        
        //return $result;
        
    }
    add_shortcode( 'site_template', 'load_my_template' );
```

If I use include_once the template would load in the page but if I use wordpress's functions like get_template_part or locate_template it doesn't load the template... since with include_function works I thought maybe I missed something else, even if I put also the complete path to the template file.... could you give me a direction?

Thanks in advance to everyone!
Cheers
Luigi

Comment: Where's the template file located? Because if for example it's in a plugin folder, then it's normal if `get_template_part()` or `locate_template()` did not load the template.

Comment: Hi Sally! Thank you for your answer...The cute thing is I debugged that TEMPLATE_MODULE_DIR . 'my-template.php' and the path in a plugin's subfolder is right... anyway the template is in the same path of the php where I call that template... In fact I was asking just because debugging all ways I get the path, absolute or relative that is, it was right but just the function wasn't loading anything... in fact as I said in my post, with include_once it loads perfectly...

Comment: Yes, and that's why I asked where the template file is located. But anyway, check my answer and see if it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment: (formatted for brevity)

> The cute thing is I debugged that `TEMPLATE_MODULE_DIR . 'my-template.php'` and the path in a plugin's subfolder is right

> in fact as I said in my post, with `include_once` it loads perfectly

So because you said it's in a **plugin** subfolder (in `wp-content/plugins`), then as I said in the comment, it's normal if `get_template_part()` or `locate_template()` did not load the template.

And that's because [`locate_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) (which is used by [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)) only searches templates in the active theme's folder in `wp-content/themes` and `wp-includes/theme-compat` if necessary, so for templates in other places like a plugin folder, you would need to use `require` or `include`, or their "_once" version. Or there's [`load_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/) if you want to use it instead.

Try placing a copy of your `my-template.php` in the active theme folder and add "test loading from the active theme folder" somewhere in the template, then see if `get_template_part()` and/or `locate_template()` now loads the template?

Comment: Hello Sally! Thanks a lot for your explanation.... in fact it was looking in template folder so just had to use include/require for plugin implementations.. thanks again